# make view table create use if conditation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

i am using codeigniter. i want to cout like this if i found 1 subject = fail 
then all result =f/fail . i how write query. i use  `group by` beasue 1 stuent have many class data .

**My table**

[image] How can write this query . i want to if one or many subject get fail mean f . 
 then getMark =f or getMark = 4.40 like .

**Query**

```
CREATE VIEW result as SELECT name as name,roll as roll,class as 
 class,subject_name as subject,exam_type as exam_type,sum(full_mark) as 
full_mark,sum(getmark) as getmark, if(gpa =='f', 'F',sum(gpa)) as 
total_gpa FROM mark GROUP by roll,class,exam_type
```

Comment: Sharing the table schema would help and a sample data with couple of rows.

Comment: check i add table photo

Comment: Have you tried CASE statements.?